# print list functional using scala

Tags: list, scala, printing, recursion, functional-programming

I have a problem: I have a list in scala like this (List("Entry1", "Entry2", "Entry3"))
and I want to print this list functional. So I don't want to use any kind of loops.

I know it is possible using some kind of this code:

```
def test(input:List[_])
input match
{
case //and what now?
case _ => //recursion I guess?

}
```

I want to print this list using this method, every element on a new line.

Could someone help me please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard way would be:

```
val xs = List("Entry1", "Entry2", "Entry3")
xs.foreach(println)
```

Or, if you want the index with it:

```
xs.zipWithIndex.foreach { case (x,i) => println(i + ": " + x) }
```

But I take it from your question that this is an exercise in writing a recursive function, so knowing the built-in way doesn't really help you.

So, if you want to do it yourself, recursively, without the built-in `foreach` method, try this:

```
@tailrec
def printList[T](list: List[T]) {
  list match {
    case head :: tail =>
      println(head)
      printList(tail)
    case Nil =>
  }
}

printList(List("Entry1", "Entry2", "Entry3"))
```

UPDATE: Regarding your comment about having the list index, try this:

```
def printList[T](list: List[T]) {
  @tailrec
  def inner(list: List[T], i: Int) {
    list match {
      case head :: tail =>
        println(i + ": " + head)
        inner(tail, i + 1)
      case Nil =>
    }
  }
  inner(list, 0)
}
```

Comment: The way you defined that, it will fail when the list is `Nil`

Comment: Is it possible to add a Nil function?

Comment: What does printList[T] (I'm talking about the T) mean?

Comment: The `T` is a generic type parameter.  It just means that the function accepts a `List` of anything, and calls that anything `T`.  Search for "scala generics" if you want to read more about it.

Comment: Oke, and is it also possible to get the list item number (like list(0) but then in the functional loop)?

Comment: Weird I'm getting for i two zero's. But your example works good, but my list looks like this: List(test1, test2) (I'm getting it from xml). But the output of your function is this: 
0: test1
0: test2
1: test2

Comment: Nevermind solved the problem! I combined your first example with the last one

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using the list API :

```
List("Entry1", "Entry2", "Entry3").zipWithIndex.foreach(t => println(t._2 + ":" + t._1))
```

Comment: @user1545846 `foreach` isn't a loop. It's a higher order function. It is definitely 1000000% better than using recursion here. You shouldn't expect the I/O operation to be "functional" anyway - it is side-effecting by nature.

Answer (score 0):

`List("LALA", "PEPE", "JOJO").map(println)`

Comment: You should use `foreach`, not `map`, because `map` will unnecessarily construct a new `List` that contains not but `Unit` instances.